# Casting data.table with conditions

Tags: r, data.table

**Problem:** In the following toy example, each ID has some states. I want to cast the output as in the code below ("Desired Output"), i.e. for each `ID` state `E` shall show up in a separate line with the same `C_` and `CMT_` states as for the other `E` states per `ID`. Any suggestions how to tackle this? Many thanks!

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  state = c("E", "C_1", "C_2", "C_3", "CMT_1", "E", "E", "E"),
  start = c("2020-03-23", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-01-23", "2020-02-23", "2019-12-23", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01"),
  end = c("2020-06-23", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-04-23", "2020-05-23", "2020-03-23", "2020-06-31", "2020-07-01"),
  CURRENT_DATE = Sys.Date()
)

dt[, tag := ifelse(CURRENT_DATE %between% .(start, end), 1, 0)]
dcast(dt, "ID + CURRENT_DATE ~ state")

## Output:
   ID CURRENT_DATE CMT_1 C_1 C_2 C_3 E
1:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 2
2:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 2

## Desired Output:
   ID CURRENT_DATE CMT_1 C_1 C_2 C_3 E
1:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 1
2:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 0
3:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 0
4:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `between` code to not include the bounds, because your desired output shows a 0 for E in the third row. Otherwise it would be 1 because today is the 31st and that's within the range (start, end) if you include the boundaries.

```
dt[, tag := as.integer(between(CURRENT_DATE, start, end, incbounds = FALSE))]

dt[, rid := rowid(state)]
wide <- 
  dcast(dt, rid + ID + CURRENT_DATE ~ state, value.var = 'tag')[, rid := NULL]

c_vars <- grep('^C', dt$state, value = TRUE)
wide[, (c_vars) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(x[which.min(is.na(x))], 0L)),
     by = ID, .SDcols = c_vars][]

#    ID CURRENT_DATE CMT_1 C_1 C_2 C_3 E
# 1:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 1
# 2:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 0
# 3:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 0
# 4:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to handle `state="E"` and `state!="E"` separately and merge:

```
setnafill(
    merge(
        dcast(dt[state!="E" & between(CURRENT_DATE, start, end)], ID + CURRENT_DATE ~ state, length),
        dt[state=="E", .(ID, CURRENT_DATE, E=+between(CURRENT_DATE, start, end))],
        by=c("ID", "CURRENT_DATE"), all=TRUE),
    fill=0L)[]
```

output:

```
   ID CURRENT_DATE CMT_1 C_1 C_2 C_3 E
1:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 1
2:  1   2020-03-31     1   1   1   1 0
3:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 1
4:  2   2020-03-31     0   0   0   0 0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    state = c("E", "C_1", "C_2", "C_3", "CMT_1", "E", "E", "E"),
    start = as.Date(c("2020-03-23", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-01-23", "2020-02-23", "2019-12-23", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01")),
    end = as.Date(c("2020-06-23", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-04-23", "2020-05-23", "2020-03-23", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-01")),
    CURRENT_DATE = as.Date("2020-03-31"))
```